# How can I convert a list of strings to a list of integers and then add them?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to convert a string list into a `int` list then add the elements.

Example:

convert `test_list = ["1", "2", "5", "6"]` to `[1, 2, 5, 6]` then add them to get `14`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> test_list = ["1", "2", "5", "6"]
>>> map(int,test_list)
[1, 2, 5, 6]
>>> sum(map(int,test_list))
14
```

Other possible ways incude

- `sum([int(i) for i in test_list])` List Comp
- `sum(int(i) for i in test_list)` Generator Expression

Note - `map` is a better alternative to list comp as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)

> map may be microscopically faster in some cases (when you're NOT
>   making a lambda for the purpose, but using the same function in map
>   and a listcomp). List comprehensions may be faster in other cases and
>   most (not all) pythonistas consider them more direct and clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```
test_list = ["1", "2", "5", "6"]

new_list = [int(x) for x in test_list]

print sum(new_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers already posted are better practice however, a very easy to understand approach would be:

```
int_list = []
count = 0
for item in test_list:
    int_list.append(int(item))
    count += int(item)
print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it's the best solution:

```
test_list = ["1", "2", "5", "6"]
def sum_strings(X):
    """changes the type to int and adds elements"""
    return reduce(lambda x, y: int(x) + int(y), X)
print sum_strings(test_list)
```

Out:

```
14
```